# Problem building flutter (3.10.5) app for IOS with XCode 14.3.1

Tags: flutter, flutter-ios-build

I am having a problem that maybe someone already solved. I mostly develop using Android Studion on Windows and everything works fine. Currently I am trying to build the same project for IOS and in the past I have used cloud macOS PCs for that purpose. In the current confiuration I have I am using Flutter 3.10.5-stable build (arm64) with Xcode 14.3.1

I followed all the steps of the documentation and I am able to Flutter Build IOS with no problem and run my app on the Simulator. However, when I try to flutter build ipa I get the following error message several times:

```
Encountered error while creating the IPA:
error: exportArchive: The operation couldn’t be completed. Unable to log in with
account '<MY EMAIL>'.
error: exportArchive: No signing certificate "iOS Distribution" found
```

I am using Atomatically manage signing with a valid account and a selected Team.

If I try to build or archive directly from the XCode I ge the following error:

```
fatal error: cannot open file '/Users/user242372/Documents/flutter/bin/cache/artifacts/engine/ios/Flutter.xcframework/ios-arm64/Flutter.framework/Modules/module.modulemap': Operation not permitted
```

I checked and that file is there.

If I try to build using a different cloud PC (with XCode 13.x - Cant remember the version) it works all fine but I cannot upload to the AppStore because it will only accept XCode 14.

I already tryed to check if there is any lack of permission for the XCode but it looks like it has full drive access. I also tryed to force the IOS Target Version to 13.0

I also tryed flutter clean, flutter pub get, pod update, pod deintegrate, pod install, but everything does not solve the problem.

Comment: i'm having exactly the same issue

Answer (score 0):

solution which worked for me from another place:

> I can't take credit for this solution, it came from BrianBatchelder on
> the apple forum.
>
> I had to go to "XCode" -> "Preferences" -> "Accounts", where it turned
> out my Apple ID had timed-out. After logging-in there, and then
> restarting Xcode, my profile was automatically "repaired", and all is
> now well.
>
> Re-starting Xcode is important there, it doesn't work without it.